# How to filter dataframe columns by correlation values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter dataframe columns by their correlation values.

I have two dataframes, d1 and d2. df2 has multiple columns and I want to select only those which a specified correlation value with df1.

I've written a function to run the correlations between df1 and df2 dataframes

```
threshold = 0.8
filter = df2.apply(lambda x: df1.corrwith(x)) > threshold
```

then I tried to use "filter" to select the columns in df2

```
df2[df2[filter]==True]
```

It didn't work, all I got is the whole df2 filled with NaN values instead of only the columns with correlation values above 0.8.

Comment: do you need ? df2[filter] ?

Comment: What's `df1.corrwith`?

Answer (score 0):

This probably works, provided that your df1 is a single-column dataframe. Credits go to @Wen-Ben.

```
df2.loc[:, [x for x in filter.iloc[0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
corr = pd.Series(df2.corrwith(df1) > threshold)  #assuming df1 has only one column

df2[corr[corr == True].index]   #This will get you required columns
```